# Can I bind the jQuery sortable 'sortstop' event to an item?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to bind the 'sortstop' event to the `li` items in a tree, instead of the `ol`.. Is this possible?

Comment: Dont think so.  But you can check the currently dragged `li` inside `sortstop` and respond as required.

Comment: I see, the problem is I'm using Backbone and the view for the `li` is in another class as the `ol`. And the view for the `li` has the model to change the attributes on, that's why I need to track the event on the `li`.. Saying that now makes me think of a solution though.. I may be able to trigger a custom event to `li` form the `ol`..

Answer (score 2):

You can bind an event on the `li`, and trigger it by doing something like:

```
$('li').on( 'sortstop', function( e, ui ) {
  // Do stuff
} );

$('ol').sortable( {
  stop: function( e, ui ){
    ui.item.trigger( e.type, ui );
  }
} );
```